# Why does every version of Selenium WebDriver give a "can not be resolved to a type" error?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to configure Selenium WebDriver to work with java bindings in Eclipse Oxygen. I've tried every single version from 2.39 to 3.8 with six different browser drivers including chrome, IE, edge, and firefox. I have followed eight different tutorials down to the t, tried numerous combinations of releases for eclipse, chromedriver, geckodriver, and webdriver, consulted the selenium forums (no one bothers to respond to anyone's questions), and finally the selenium IRC (once again no one bothers to respond to anyone). The errors that I am getting are as follows:

[image]

**"The package org.openqa.selenium is accessible from more than one module:"**
I tried specifying every single possible module (one at a time), to pull from and none of the versions even have anything remotely similar to org.openqa.selenium.Webdriver. No matter how I specify the module, I get **"org.openqa.selenium.Webdriver can not be resolved to a type."**

I checked to make sure that I included all the .jar files, I checked to see if the path I specified for chromedriver is correct, I checked if I misspelled anything, configuration of eclipse, configuration of package, configuration of the class, configuration of even the workspace etc. Still I can't find why these errors keep occurring.

It seems that a large number of people across various versions, in numerous threads on google are having this issue and the only solution anyone is offering is to make sure all the .jar files are included in the build path. I have done so for every single version with no success.

Have any of you had something similar to this? Have any of you managed to resolve the issue, if so how did you do it? Any assistance with this would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can I have a look at your exact configuration you are trying to set up along with the Selenium, WebDriver & Web Browser versions?

Comment: Please righ-click on the project, then choose `Properties`, then click on `Java Build Path` option, then click on `Libraries` tab, take a schreenschot of a dialog and attach it to the question.

Comment: @krokodilko Thank you both for the response. I added the build path screenshot to my question. They are currently in the download folder but that wouldn't normally be the case as I'm trying to test to see which version will get it to work.

Comment: @DebanjanB right now, I'm just trying to set up the environment and write a basic script to test if it is working. I'm running webdriver 3.8.1 with chromedriver 2.2 on the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: I wonder why you are not using maven or gradle yet, but you are still adding libraries manually. Follow this tutorial : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html  create a maven project, and then just add this simple entry to the POM.XML --> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.8.1 to the dependencies section, and you will not have to worry about adding libraries, Maven will do it for you

Comment: @TfwBear One way of doing this is to move the jar files into the classpath instead of modulepath in the project build path. Let only the JRE 9 system library remain in the modulepath. Lookup Maven, avoids classpath issues as suggested above. Though if you are looking for a Java 9 solution with modules this is not the way to go.

Comment: @Grasshopper I tried using it in the classpath to no avail. I'll try using Maven and report back.

Comment: @TfwBear i tried using the classpath and it works perfectly. Maybe you should try with a new project.

Comment: @Grasshopper I did a completely fresh install and it worked. New workspace, new package, new project, moved the libraries into project directory, moved chromedriver into directory, imported via classpath rather than module path. Everything worked out. Thank you so much for your help.